# AngularJs directive for disable button after click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need a directive for disable a button on click.I want to be an attribute, and the click event to detect in the directive not to pass it on a function. After i detect the event i want to disable using "data-ng-disabled". I am a little stuck, if you can give me some indications how can I solve it.

Comment: can you pls add more info? you can post the code you tried.

Comment: If you want to disable using "data-ng-disabled", you are already using a built-in directive provided by angularjs, which you map to a scope variable to disable/enable the button. Not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the link function to do that

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive('disableOnClick', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.isDesabled = false;
      element.bind('click', () => {
        element[0].disabled = true;
      });
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <button disable-on-click>Click to disable me</button>
</body>

</html>
```